# write two msg simultenously in eclipse workbench status line

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have program which set a message in status line as

```
monitor.beginTask("XYZ...", 10); 

in a run method of a classs which implements IRunnableWithProgress
```

which displays on left corner message area. is it possible to write another message in status line excluding this message area which displays simultaneously with previous one?

Please help any suggestion will be appreciated.

thanks.

[image]

Comment: why not appending the new message with this message only with help of any seperator

Comment: @bunta i want to show in separate message area.. i am adding a image which clears out very well i hope

Comment: @all as message are displaying in separate region.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the status bar can contain only one message at a time.  You can append it to the statusbar message if you desire....or write a statusbar service class (register it with Eclipse) and manage all of the status bar messages you desire!  I'm not sure the service is worth the effort or not in your case though.